# 410 permanent delete not working

Tags: http

I've deleted a web page permanently and also added this rule in the bottom of my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^paysignet-payment-gateway-features-and-benefits.html$ - [G,L]
```

But this url of this page: http://www.creditcardpaymentgateways.in/paysignet-payment-gateway-features-and-benefits.html is returning 404 from the server rather than a 410.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try putting that line at the top of your .htaccess file instead of at the bottom. It's possible that another RewriteRule is taking effect before that one. (Probably one that also uses an L/last flag, which would mean your 410 rule would never be evaluated.)

Comment: Thanks it works. I placed all those in the very first line of .htaccess. I hope there won't be any issues!